# How to get values in array of array in angular?

Tags: angular

I am getting the table column name as a status and I need to change the color of the buttons based on status value.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="agentName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Agent Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.agent_id.company_name}}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><span class="dot" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getRowColor()}"></span></td>
</ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
// ...

export class Component {
    red = { 'background-color': 'red' }
    yellow = { 'background-color': '#DAA520' }
    green = { 'background-color': '#00FF00' }
    pageSizeOptions: number[];
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['title', 'agentName', 'status', 'star'];
    dat: any[] = [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Test',
    }];
    state : any = [];
    getPos: any = [];

    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<{}>;
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

    constructor(
        private store: Store<IAppState>,
        private userService: UserService,
        private poService: PoService,
        private propertiesService: PropertiesService,
        private _location: Location,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getAllPO()
        this.pageSizeOptions = this.propertiesService.getPaginationSize()
    }

    edit(data) {
        this.poService.changeEditPurchaseOrder(data)
    }

    getAllPO() {
        const payload = {
            'company_id': this.userService.getUserdetails().CompanyUser.company_id.id,
        }

        this.showSpinner = true
        this.poSuccessSubscription.unsubscribe()
        this.poErrorSubscription.unsubscribe()
        this.store.dispatch(new GetAllPOs(payload))

        this.poSuccessSubscription = this.store
            .pipe(select(getAllPOsSuccess))
            .subscribe((result: any) => {
                if (!!result) {
                    this.getPos = result
                    this.state = this.getPos.find(element => {
                        return element.POMaterials.find(item =>{
                            return item.state
                        })
                    })
                    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result)
                    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                    this.showSpinner = false
                } else {
                    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([])
                    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                    this.showSpinner = false
                }
            })

        this.poErrorSubscription = this.store
            .pipe(select(getAllPOsError))
            .subscribe((result: any) => {
                if (!!result) {
                    // alert(result.error)
                    this.showSpinner = false
                }
            })
    }

    getRowColor(state) {
        if (state === 'Not Received') {
            return 'red'
        } else if (state === 'Completed') {
            return '#00FF00'
        }
        else {
            return '#DAA520'
        }
    }

    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
        if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
            this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
        }
    }
}
```

My data looks like this. I need to get the value of state in each array and assign it to each row. Based on state value, I need to change the color of the buttons.

```
const result = [{
    Pomaterials: [{
        id: 1,
        state: 'not received'
    }],
    po_id: 1,
    mat_id: 3
}, {
    Pomaterials: [{
        id: 1,
        state: 'not received'
    }],
    po_id: 1,
    mat_id: 2
}];
```

Comment: I think you are looping through the result in your HTML. Can you please add that?

Comment: Reasoning about data structures when the lack of indentation makes it impossible to see it is quite hard. Start by doing the obvious: indent the code properly. Your IDE/editor can do that for you. Then please, clarify your question.

Comment: To add to the previous comment. Please share your entire component code(.ts and .html). There are a lot of missing pieces of functionality. I'm not able to connect any dots. Help us help you...

Comment: Now i edited my question.. you could check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML and your JSON result is confusing:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.agent_id.company_name}} </td>
```

And

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result)
```

imply you should have an agent_id object, like:

```
const result = [
    {
      Pomaterials: [
        { 
         id:1,
         state:"not received"
        }
      ]
      po_id:1,
      mat_id:3,
      agent_id: {
          company_name: "Company"
      }
    },
    ...
]
```

Anyway, your getRowColor(state) function has a state param and you don't provide any from the HTML:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><span class="dot" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getRowColor()}"></span> </td>
```

As element is a row of your JSON result, you may try:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><span class="dot" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getRowColor(element.Pomaterials[0].state)}"></span> </td>
```

Only if your Pomaterials is always built like the JSON result you provide us.

If you need to loop over Pomaterials array for setting the state you can do something like:

```
this.poSuccessSubscription = this.store
    .pipe(select(getAllPOsSuccess))
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
      if (!!result) {
        ...
        this.getPos.forEach(element => {
          element.finalState = evalFinalStateElement(element.Pomaterials);
        });
        ...
      }
      ...
});

evalFinalStateElement(Pomaterials: Array<any>) {
  let finalState;
  Pomaterials.forEach(Po => {
    if(!finalState) {
      finalState = Po.state;
    }
    else if(finalState === 'XXX' && Po.state === 'YYY') {
      finalState = Po.state
    }
    // ...
  });
  return finalState;
}
```

And then use the defined element.finalState variable inside your HTML:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><span class="dot" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getRowColor(element.finalState)}"></span> </td>
```

with the getRowColor(state) function you posted.

Comment: You should post as a code snippet. I'm not sure if this is actually any better than what OP posted :(

Comment: thank you so much... its working fine when i approach through html..

Comment: But if i have more than 1 POmaterials in an array.. then how can we approach??

Answer (score 0):

You can send the whole POmaterials array as param of the getRowColor function and iter on elements for finding your value. Can you tell us what you want to do with your array?

Comment: Hi Pierre-Henri. You can answer to comments in the comment section (click the "add a comment" link underneath the comment). No need to make a separate answer for that.

Comment: i need to filter the value based on state in each array..before doing this i need to get together value of state in each array.. For example case1: pomaterials[0].state = "Not received" , pomaterials[1].state ="Completed" then final state should be not received.. First thing i need to get final state to loopover the array then based on those state i need to do filter opertion.. could you please help me out??

Comment: Hi TT, sorry for the bad posting, I am new on stackoverflow and just understand that using the website from my smartphone is not as good using my computer. I'd like to fix it but I think it is too late now.

Comment: Rekha, I updated my answer, not 100% sure it is what you need, let me now.

Comment: I got an error in ForEach of undefined in evalFinalstatevalue(element.Pomaterials)..

Comment: yes, it works.. but I am not able to understand why ur comparing final state and po.state?? is it working if pomaterials have 3 arrays?? please let me know??

Comment: For example case2: pomaterials[0].state = "Not received" , pomaterials[1].state ="Completed". pomaterials[3].state = 'partial received' then final state should be not received.. case 3:pomaterials[0].state = "partial received" , pomaterials[1].state ="Completed". pomaterials[3].state = 'partial received then final state should be partial received.. these cases also considerable..

Comment: Your examples always return pomaterials[0]. Is it what you want or, if you have, for example,  case4: pomaterials[0].state = "partial received" , pomaterials[1].state ="Completed". pomaterials[3].state = ''Not received" then final state is also "not received" as your case2?

Comment: pomaterials is getting dynamic arrays.. it can be n number of values.. based on those values i need to get final state.. could you possibly do this??